# basis of subspace $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the subspace of $R^4$ consisting of all vectors of the form $(a,b,c,d)$  where $c=a+6b$ and $d=a-3b$

I've sat and thought about how to even start this problem and have no idea. Suggestions please!

Comment: replace c and d in your vector. Write what you get as a linear combination of 2 fixed vectors in $R^4$. What does that sum mean?

Comment: $(a,b,c,d) = (a,b,a+6b,a-3b) = a(1,0,1,1)+b(0,1,6,-3)$. What does that tell you? If you are not sure re-read about linear combinations, spanning sets and the definition of a basis.

Comment: @Paul, why not write this as an answer? I was about to write, more or less, your comment for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call the subspace $W$. Then $W$ consists of all the points $(a,b,c,d)$ that are solutions to those two equations. Those two *linear* equations. In other words, $W$ is the set of all solutions to a particular system of linear equations. And I'm willing to bet you've previously learned how to solve systems of linear equations. So all you have to do is solve them, and give a basis for the solution set.

Comment: I kind of see where you are going with this.

Comment: For whatever reason I am still having difficulty with it. Is there anyway you can show me?